# Embedding an excel file using python-pptx: add_ole_object

Tags: python, powerpoint, ole, python-pptx

I am trying to embed an excel file with data to a powerpoint file, but when I run the code, it adds an empty excel file instead of the excel file which has data (Test.xlsx).

Below is the code I ran,

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches 

ppt = Presentation()
title_slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(ppt.slide_layouts[0])
title_slide.shapes.add_ole_object('Test.xlsx', 'Excel.Sheet', left = Inches(1), top = Inches(3))
ppt.save('Test.pptx')
```

This is documentation I referred,

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html

I am unsure if I am running it incorrectly. I would appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this, so for the Prog_ID, instead of 'Excel.Sheet' I had to use PROG_ID.XLSX. I imported PROG_ID using 'from pptx.enum.shapes import PROG_ID'. In case anyone has this problem, hopefully this helps.

Source: github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/752

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).